# SQL Server 2016 - Mirroring Errors - Non Domain Servers

Tags: sql

I've been looking at lots of posts and videos about how 'easy' it is to get SQl Mirroring Setup..

However what most posts and videos fail to inform its readers is that all your sql servers have to be on the the same network\domain to make it 'easy'.

Question:
Is it possible to setup SQL Mirroring on two different computers that are not on the same domain\network? or do they have to be on the same domain?

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about database mirroring? If so I would not recommend doing this since it is going to be deprecated eventually. I would recommend using Always on Failover Clusters or Always On Availability Groups if you can. More info on this page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190202.aspx. I am fairly sure both can be setup in workgroups but I have never done it before.

Comment: I Believe i looked at this first and requires an active directory setup, which defeats the setup I have